# Low active TCP connections vs high \Device\Afd handles

Tags: .net, iis, tcp, port, handle

Every few months on a Windows server where I have a few .NET Core 3.1 web applications running in IIS, I see TCP port exhaustion errors being logged, with all the associated symptoms happening (unable to open more network ports to connect to database server, domain controller, etc.)

Looking at `netstat -anob` traces when this happens, the number of active connections is surprisingly only in the hundreds range for the whole system, and there's only a handful in TIME_WAIT state.

However, looking at the number of handles held by processes with Process Explorer and `handle.exe`, it turns out one website (w3wp process) has 31000 handles and growing, most of which are `\Device\Afd` file handles, which seems to point to a network handle leak problem.

Restarting the website in IIS solves the issue.

- How come the huge number of handles doesn't show at all in the TCP ports open in `netstat` traces? You would think a port exhaustion problem is visible in a tool that is supposed to report network stats.
- More generally, how do `\Device\Afd` handles relate to TCP ports in the system/network stack? Troubleshoot pages like [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/tcp-ip-port-exhaustion-troubleshooting) mention them but don't explain a lot.
- Any idea what type of problem manifests itself like that? Suggestions for tools to to identify the faulty part of the website/app?

Comment: The problem you are experiencing is really difficult to diagnose. Perhaps the debug diagnostic tool (DebugDiag) can be a savior. It supports conditional and on-demand collection of memory dump files using configurable rules that trigger collection. However, analyzing dump files is a complicated process. I recommend that you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, there will be professional technicians to assist you in grabbing the dump file and analyzing it.